# Create private cocoapod available to authenticated users

Tags: git, server, cocoapods

I need to create a private cocoapod that will be available only to a few users identified with a token or loging/password.

Does anybody know a service like gemfury (even if not free) that does it ? 
If not, could somebody explain me how I could make it ?

I already tried to make my own git server but didn't succeed to use it with Pod file.
Also, I need to have a kind of BaseAuthentication in the pods urls in order to have only one account per clients (see clients as a company that has a bunch of iOS developers)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org) for hosting your repository. And you give source line like this :

source 'git@bitbucket.org:YourRepo/Your-podspecs.git

instead of using https repo URL...

Then you can manage users on Bitbucket.

Comment: Not bad, but I forgot to tell that I would like to avoid registering external git users and prefer to use logins that I create. Otherwise I will need to register every iOS developpers of our clients' companies instead of generating a single login per companies.